# How to get http refere in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I would like to get from which page a user came from in my page.

Currently, I would like to get this info in my created() or mounted() pages.  Using this.$router or this.$route but none of them contain this info.

I know in the navigation guards, we can use this :

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => { })
```

to know where the page is comming from, but I don't want to use router.beforeEach because that is in found inside my main.js but where I want to get the referer is in my components page, either in created/mounted methods

Is this possible?

Comment: You can either pass the router down as a prop, or use some kind of event system detailed here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced

Comment: what do you mean "pass the router down as a prop"? I could not find that on the doc

Comment: @hidar This is the document you are looking for. https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.$route.query` in mounted() hook in App.vue. You don't need router.beforeEach, because it dosn't make sense. App.vue mounted one time, when app is loaded, so this a good place to check router query params.

Comment: i trying this now and it works perfectly. my code in mounted:
`console.log(this.$route.query);` and url `product/3?utm_source=2`. Console logs `{utm_source: "2"}`

Comment: hm.. sorry for the late response, I stumbled again on this issue and I still can not the referer. I have this code: `mounted () {
    console.log('this.$route.query', this.$route.query)
  }`

Comment: I don't know what else I can do to get the the referer. Do I need to pass a prop or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
       console.log(to.query)
       console.log(to.query.utm_source)
})
```

if url `product/3?utm_source=2.` 
Console logs

```
{utm_source: "2"}
2
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => { })
```

look for `to.fullPath`. It's your redirect link