# VueJs get referral URL that called a specific route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to get the **referral URL** from where a specific route from my VueJS app was called.

The flow is:

1. *Route1* redirects to (outside) *URL1* with a *returnURL*
2. (outside) *URL1* performs some actions and returns to *returnURL*
3. *ReturnUrl* matches *Route2* and shows a view **(only if it comes from *URL1*)**

I've tried with:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log(to)
  console.log(from)
  next()
})
```

But the `from` url is always `/`. Also I tried with:

```
this.$route.query
```

(from [How to get http refere in vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48265620/how-to-get-http-refere-in-vuejs))

And with plain JS with something like:

```
var referrer = document.referrer;
```

Finally I tried with this [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tozd/vue-router-referer) without success.

The problem is that I don't have any clue if the user called directly the `returnUrl` (forbidden) or it's a call from the outside service `URL1` (valid).

It's this possible?

I checked:
[Can I get the referrer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856697/can-i-get-the-referrer)

Comment: When generating the `returnURL` you can include a query variable inside it - and then check for this query variable inside `route2`. Obviously it should not be a static value but some cryptographically encrypted string - otherwise the user can bypass your "protection".

Comment: This not work for me, because is a JS app and the user could easily check the query variable in the code.

Comment: Your issue is not if the user can check the variable - but whether he can tamper it. If the variable contains encrypted value (e.g. using AES-256) the user can see it but if he change it you will easily detect this and refuse to perform the action or show the page.

Answer (score 1):

**Please check this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-get-referral-url-that-called-a-specific-route-qzumx for updated solution.**

#### use vue-router (only works within the app)

A possibly useful hook of vue-router to use here is `beforeRouteEnter`, docs [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html). It is called before the route that renders this component is confirmed. The idea is that, in this vue-router hook, we can set the `previousPath` property and leverage it in the Vue component.

However, as vue-router only have access to route changes within the app, it can't help get the previous URL when the visitor comes from links outside.

#### use encrypted params (only when you can edit the link in the 'source')

An alternative solution is to alter the URL, by adding an encrypted parameter in the URL about current timestamp. In the app, we decrypt the parameter, compare two timestamps, and only return true when the time difference is within some threshold like 5s.

With this approach, only when visitors are coming into your app following the link would the validation method returns `true`. The link would expire in 5s, so if malicious user copy/paste the link, it won't work. As it's being encrypted, altering the URL params manually also won't work.

As for the encryption method, I'm using the simplest Base64-encoding approach [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) without 3rd party library. Of course, you can switch it to some other encryption libraries. However, using a timestamp as the key would be a possible solution for your requirements.

You can also easily encrypt/decrypt and verify other params, including source URL with this approach.

Comment: This not work for me, as I want to know if the URL was called by an external site. With this approach I only know if the URL is accessed via a link or directly

Comment: @JP.Aulet Please check my updated answer with an alternative solution. It would help ensure to verify that links only come from your 'outside service URL1 (valid)'.

Comment: Sorry, but I need to know the external URL that calls the roure. A bit like Google Analytics to be able to know where people comes from.

Comment: @JP.Aulet That would be easy to implement, please view my updated demo in the posted link. You can verify the source URL through encrypted params as well.